# In Eclipse, how to open a file browser in the directory of the currently edited file

Tags: eclipse, file-browser

I know it's possible in eclipse to [open file browsers from your project's resource browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161240/in-eclipse-reveal-current-file-in-filesystem), but is it possible for files that aren't part of your project ? Typically external includes are not found in your resource browser...

If there is the equivalent of $(resource_loc) for the editor, it would work.. But I wasn't able to find it. Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanks!

EDIT : I Found [StartExplorer](http://startexplorer.sourceforge.net/), but it doesn't work for me. It is hardcoded to use **WINDOWS explorer** or **cmd.exe**. Also, it still requires you to use the resource browser. Other than that it can open paths selected in the editor, but they must be full paths.

EDIT 2 : StartExplorer seems to have been upgraded. I no longer use eclipse, but if someone else is still looking for this, I'd look again at their stuff!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`"Window" -> "Open Perspectives" -> "Remote Systems"`, then a view with root 'Local' node will be displayed.

While in Project Explorer pane, to browse files of any node, right click and select `Show in Remote Systems view` to get there.

[image]

Comment: Seems like RSE is deprecated. No longer shipped with Eclipse, but you have to install from Marketplace. http://www.eclipse.org/tm/

Answer (score 22):

For eclipse Luna (4.4) and later, You can use: Right Click->Show In->System Explorer
[image]

Comment: this is a most easy way, non plugin, non external cmd

Comment: I'm assuming the other answers pre-date this functionality because this is definitely the right answer now.

Comment: oxygen no this menu.

Comment: @chansey This menu is in Oxygen.

Comment: chansey: as @wisbucky said, It is in oxygen. I modified the answer to indicate that it is in Luna 4.4 or later.

Answer (score 5):

From [StartExplorer](http://basti1302.github.io/startexplorer) website:

> This plug-in is inherently not platform-independent. Currently, the following operating systems/desktop environments are supported out of the box: Windows, Mac OS, Linux with Gnome, Linux with KDE, Linux with Xfce, Linux with LXDE.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you have to [create a linked folder](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-45.htm) for your external includes to achieve your goal. After that you can use StartExplorer for you externals as well. If you do not like that plugin you could try another similar one called [EasyShell](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell) which is a similar one but you can configure all of its commands.

Answer (score 3):

[EasyShell](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell?mpc=true&mpc_state=#.Utuatfj8L-s) seems quite descent to me (used in Ubuntu). It gives you the choices to **open the Nautilus**, to **open the shell**, to **run a file** and to **copy the selected path**. All of them appear with a right click on the package explorer of Eclipse. The installation was with no problems. Therefore, I would suggest it.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [eExplorer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eexplorer), see my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24149472/612123

Answer (score 1):

If you are using git, you can open Window > Show View > Other > Git Repositories. That will give you a Git Repositories explorer, which shows the Working Tree. The Working Tree will show all files in the filesystem, even temporary ones you created that are not added to git yet.

Another way is to open Window > Perspective > Other > Git.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut key can also be created in Eclipse>Help>Preferences>General>Keys