# Eclipse Plugin to "Open Explorer in this File location" for Package Explorer

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Is there any plugin that lets me open the file I selected in the Package Explorer in windows explorer?
I am looking for an extra menu option in the right click menu of the package explorer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Eclipse, how to open a file browser in the directory of the currently edited file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419954/in-eclipse-how-to-open-a-file-browser-in-the-directory-of-the-currently-edited)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmmm... Looks like we all have this problem. 
You can use [this](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pextools) plugin to do exactly that and a bit more...

Sorry for self advertising... But I think this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Compared with some of the other plugins that try (and fail) to do the same open-in-explorer/terminal/etc function, PexTools works extremely well.

Answer (score 14):

Since [Eclipse 4.4 (Luna)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.4/eclipse-news-part1.php) there is a *Show in System Explorer* command available from the context menu.

[image]

The *Show In* menu is also accessible through <kbd>Alt+Shift+W</kbd> on Linux/Windows and <kbd>Alt+Cmd+W</kbd> on macOS.

While there is a default setting that is suitable in most cases, the command for launching the system explorer can be configured on the *General > Workspace* preference page.

Comment: I think you meant Eclipse **4.4** Luna.

Comment: @MuhammadAnnaqeeb You are right, thanks for the hint. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: It looks like this feature is gone in oxygen

Comment: @ST-DDT No, it isn't. Note, that the selection needs to represent a resource in order for _Show in System Explorer_ to work. If you still don't see the command, please provide the exact details of what you are trying (probably best asked in a separate post).

Comment: Thanks for the <kbd>Alt+Shift+W</kbd> . This is the only option I have on my "branded" eclipse 4.4.2

Answer (score 7):

I'm using [StartExplorer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/641101) for several years now. It's easy to use, is up-to-date and does simply, what you are expecting from it. You can install it through

```
Help > Eclipse Marketplace...
```

Usage:

[image: example usage]

Answer (score 2):

If you can live without the context menu, you can even get this without any additional plugin, using just a [launch configuration on the active selection](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t77655.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip and link, very interesting

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a direct way, but what you can do is right click on the file/folder, go to properties, then copy "Location" and put that string into a blank explorer window.

so,

right-click --> properties -->  Location --> ctrl-c

open explorer window --> ctrl-v --> go button

Comment: I understand, I wouldn't want to do that either any time you need to see it in the explorer window :(

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eexplorer

- keeps windows explorer in sync without the need to sync manually via context menu
- less explorer windows -> less clutter
- possibility to pop out native explorer
- keyboard short cuts

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple plugin with just shell & file explorer

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/open-here-eclipse