# Eclipse show project in explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In eclipse, reveal current file in filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161240/in-eclipse-reveal-current-file-in-filesystem)

How can I show the project in explore mode. In windows, if we right click the project and go to properties, project location is stated there. But is there any shortcut to get to the project directory?

Comment: Thank you. But I believe it used to be that we could explore the project by just right clicking. Has that been removed? This is what I am looking for.

Comment: I just voted to re-open this question so I can answer. Here is how: install [EasyShell](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell), then right-click on the project in the Project Explorer and go to Easy Shell --> "Open with Default Application", "Copy full path to clipboard", or "Copy qualified name to clipboard".

Comment: @GabrielStaples Why not post your answer on the duplicate?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks. The "duplicate" link is missing in the grey box indicating to people of high enough reputation that the question is closed. Then I realized a link has been manually added to the question itself. I just posted my answer here: [How to use the EasyShell plugin in Eclipse to quickly jump to a file or folder or copy its path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74617485/4561887)

Comment: @GabrielStaples It is not missing, this question was closed so long ago, it still uses the "old" way of listing duplicates in the question body itself. It wasn't manually added though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. I don't know of an option that used to exist to allow that. There is the "Show In" menu but that is only to show things in other parts of Eclipse.

Comment: ...but there are plug-ins and alternatives that allow for this as pointed out in the highly accepted answer of a duplicate question...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161240/in-eclipse-reveal-current-file-in-filesystem